# CMake install component does not work as expected

Tags: c++, cmake

I have multiple targets (each in it's one CMakeLists.txt) in my CMake project. A few libraries and one executable. As I want to install all the libs to a certain location and the executable to another location my plan was to group all the libs in one COMPONENT and the executable in another component. Here the install command of the CMakeLists.txt of the executable:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION usr/lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION usr/lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION usr/local/bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION usr/include
  COMPONENT hal_server_component
)
```

Now if run

```
cmake -B <builddir> -S <sourcedir> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cmake --build <builddir>
cmake --install <builddir> --prefix <installation-prefix> --component hal_server_component
```

Nothing is getting installed to `<installation-prefix>/usr/local/bin`. I inspected the cmake_install.cmake file which was generated by this command `cmake -B <builddir> -S <sourcedir> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`. There is this if statement generated in the file:

```
if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xUnspecifiedx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
   .... # target get's installed here
```

if I changes this line manually to:

```
if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xhal_server_componentx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
   .... # target get's installed here
```

The command `cmake --install <builddir> --prefix <installation-prefix> --component hal_server_component` installs the target as expected to this location `<installation-prefix>/usr/local/bin`.
So my assumption is that cmake does not recognize the `COMPONENT hal_server_component` in my CMakeLists.txt file and through that not generates the cmake_install.cmake file correctly. Am I specifying the COMPONENT correctly in my CMakeLists.txt? Is there anything I understood incorrectly about how to use Components in CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COMPONENT` option describes a particular **artifact** (LIBRARY, ARCHIVE, RUNTIME, etc.), so it should **follow** specification of the artifact. An artifact could be described by several options (e.g. DESTINATION also describes the artifact), which could come in any relative order.

But `INCLUDES` is not an artifact description! So CMake interprets your `install` as follows:

```cmake
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} # Targets to be installed
EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets # Export file
  LIBRARY # Artifact name
  # Begin description of the artifact LIBRARY
  DESTINATION usr/lib # DESTINATION specification of the artifact
  # End description of the artifact LIBRARY: next option denotes artifact name
  ARCHIVE # Artifact name
  # Begin description of the artifact ARCHIVE
  DESTINATION usr/lib # DESTINATION specification of the artifact
  # End description of the artifact ARCHIVE: next option denotes artifact name
  RUNTIME # Artifact name
  # Begin description of the artifact RUNTIME
  DESTINATION usr/local/bin # DESTINATION specification of the artifact
  # End description of the artifact RUNTIME: next option is a generic one
  # Generic options
  INCLUDES DESTINATION usr/include
  COMPONENT hal_server_component
)
```

That is, CMake doesn't treat your COMPONENT as corresponding to the RUNTIME artifact.

You need to specify COMPONENT before the INCLUDES:

```cmake
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} # Targets to be installed
EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets # Export file
  LIBRARY # Artifact name
  # Begin description of the artifact LIBRARY
  DESTINATION usr/lib # DESTINATION specification of the artifact
  # End description of the artifact LIBRARY: next option denotes artifact name
  ARCHIVE # Artifact name
  # Begin description of the artifact ARCHIVE
  DESTINATION usr/lib # DESTINATION specification of the artifact
  # End description of the artifact ARCHIVE: next option denotes artifact name
  RUNTIME # Artifact name
  # Begin description of the artifact RUNTIME
  DESTINATION usr/local/bin # DESTINATION specification of the artifact
  COMPONENT hal_server_component # COMPONENT specification of the artifact
  # End description of the artifact RUNTIME: next option is a generic one  
  # Generic options
  INCLUDES DESTINATION usr/include
)
```

---

Technically, your original code **contradicts** to the syntax of [install(TARGET)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets): A *generic* option cannot be a COMPONENT. So one could expect CMake to emit an error. Unfortunately, CMake error reporting for a complex syntax (like in `install(TARGETS)` command) is far from ideal.